# stop scroll bar from covering div content with auto overflow

Tags: html, css

I have this div with `overflow-y:auto;` which can be very narrow and when the scroll bar appears it can cover much or all of the div. I would like the scroll bar to appear outside the div like with `overflow:scroll;` but I don't want to see the faded scroll bar when there is no overflow. Also I don't want to  give the div a width as the width must be variable. This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUYVe/)  demonstrates my issue, and here is the code:

```
   .auto {
            display:inline-block;
            border:1px solid green;
            height:70px; 
            overflow-y:auto; 
         }

<div class = "auto">
  <div>
    a<br>
    b<br>
    c<br>
    d<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow-y` and `display: inline-block;` doesn't make any sense to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUYVe/5/

Basically, it uses a wrapper to contain the scrollbar

```
<div class="scroll">
  <div>a
    <br />b
    <br />c
    <br />d
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

and leaves some space on the right side for it:

```
padding-right: 13px;
```

However, since scrollbars may vary depending on OS, I'd suggest to use custom scrollbars like [this jQuery plugin](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/).

Comment: Thanks for the plugin link.. I think you gave me the wrong jsfiddle link, this is the original fiddle version that I posted

Comment: thank you very much for the new fiddle.A great solution for me. I will be using it.

Answer (score 3):

Give 18px padding right to .auto class it will be help you.

```
   .auto   {
       border:1px solid green;
       height:70px; 
       overflow-y:auto; 
       display:inline-block;
       padding-right:18px;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUYVe/3/)add a min-width to it and a max-width. this way it stays `variable`

Comment: thanks for the jsfiddle. it's a good solution in part, but zoom out to 67% and its covered again.

Comment: then give it like `padding-right:5px;` but is it realy going to be such a smal div?

Comment: it can be as little as 1 letter wide. unlikely, but possible. I will try with the padding-right